# Call forwarding from one function to another

Tags: javascript

Why this code works? After all, we call g in the context of null. Roughly speaking call the function g as an object method null?

```
function f(a, b) {
  g.apply(null, arguments);
}
```

Comment: You call `g` with `this` set to `null`, if `g` doesn't use `this`, then it doesn't matter what its value is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to call it this way if `this` is never used within `g`'s body.

Note that one often has no alternatives to `apply` when passing arguments from outer function (a facade) to a specific implementation, when the former is a variadic function - both `call` and direct invokation require list of arguments.

If `null` or `undefined` is supplied, and the function is called like this in a non-strict mode, it will be replaced with the global object ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)).

Comment: Do I understand correctly? this is not needed as such. We need to pass an array of arguments for the use of this method apply. Method syntax has the required parameter "call context." Therefore, specify a null. This for g will be the same as that for f global object.

Comment: Yes, that's correct - unless the function is called in strict mode. Quoting the docs: *...if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.*